# How do I implement numeral-only validation for a TextBox?

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation

I would like to restrict the contents of a TextBox to contain only five digits.  Could you please suggest a way to do so?

Comment: My question is if you want to check this on validation or on a keystroke. If you want to do it on validation you can use the .NET validator. Else you have to look at a javascript solution. I can provide you one.

Comment: thank u where it is mr.joop (javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$
```

that permits all decimal numbers.

Edit:

```
^\d{1,5}$
```

Eact 5 digits

```
^\d{5}$
```

Comment: Do you need exact 5 digits or upto 5 digits?

Comment: xact 5 digits not less than 5 and not more than 5

Answer (score 3):

here is validation expression
     ^\d{1,5}$

But its preferable to use `RangeValidator`

```
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="rngv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt"
      ErrorMessage="1 to 99999 is Allowed" MaximumValue="99999" MinimumValue="1"
      SkinID="validation" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: Good to suggest RangeValidator.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than playing around with regular expressions and validators I would have said the easiest way to implement this is to use the [FilteredTextBox extender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) from the Ajax ControlToolkit which has the built-in capability to restrict entry to just numbers.
Then set the MaxLength property on the TextBox to 5.

Answer (score 0):

put this in expression 
^\d{5}$